# MonogoDB: Deleting duplicate sub-documents

Tags: mongodb

Being completely new to MongoDB, I am finding this challenging. I need to delete all but 1 sub-document if a sub-document field has specific value.

Below is example of the source MongoDB document and sub-documents:

```
{
  _id: <some_UUID>,
  fieldA: "<some_fieldA_value>,
  subDocA: [
    {
      subFieldA: "aaa",
      subFieldB: "bbb"
    },
    {
      subFieldA: "aaa",
      subFieldB: "ccc"
    },
    {
      subFieldA: "aa1",
      subFieldB: "ddd"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the target MongoDb document should be:

```
{
  _id: <some_UUID>,
  fieldA: "<some_fieldA_value>,
  subDocA: [
    {
      subFieldA: "aaa",
      subFieldB: "bbb"
    },
    {
      subFieldA: "aa1",
      subFieldB: "ddd"
    }
  ]
}
```

That is if sub-document field subFieldA=aaa, then keep only 1 such sub-document in the parent document.

Can someone help me for coming up with MongoDB query? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The sub-document may not have same value for other fields. And there can be many such documents in the collection for which I need to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this aggregation pipeline.

- First `$unwind` to deconstruct the array.
- Then `$group` twice: First time group by `subFieldA` value to get the `$first` one. Second time to get the original structure.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$subDocA"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$subDocA.subFieldA",
      "subDocA": {
        "$first": "$subDocA"
      },
      "fieldA": {
        "$first": "$fieldA"
      },
      "id": {
        "$first": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "fieldA": {
        "$first": "$fieldA"
      },
      "subDocA": {
        "$push": "$subDocA"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/93ntUg5rcIe)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I was not specific in my initial question. I updated the question - the sub-document may not have same other fields and so the $setToUnion does not work. Basically, I need to delete all sub-documents with subFieldA=aaa except 1.

Comment: Hi @MB1986, sorry for misunderstood your question, I've edited the question and I think this is a better approach.